# Calculate place of point C to be equal distance away from points A and B

Tags: trigonometry, game-maker

In the picture below I have a triangle. It represents a mechanical arm, where

- A = Shoulder (base point of the object)
- B = Hand (turret that shoots at the player)
- C = Elbow
- x = Upper arm (same length as z)
- y = Distance between Shoulder and Hand
- z = Lower arm (same length as x)

Point B can freely move around point A as long as it doesn't go too far away (pre-determined value). The position of point C should be calculated so that the lines x and z doesn't suffer any changes in length. In other words, point C has to stay a pre-determined distance away from points A and B. How should I calculate this?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about maths, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

First observation (you can't overstretch and you can't touch your shoulder if your under arm is shorter than your upper arm):
| x - z | <= | y | <= | x + z |

Next, it can be calculated with the cosine rule, where you can calculate any angle you want (e.g. angle a = CAB).
From there  you can calculate C.